# ios sdk facebook graph api, unable to post image to a facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo, facebook-page

When I try to post image to facebook page using the graph api, page_id/photos with source and message parameter. But what happens is it posts on my wall instead of the page wall.
Do any one have a similar problem?
Can some give a solution or a work around for this problem..

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

me/photos works when posting a UIImage but 3453455345/photos ends up on my wall as well. Even though users can publicly post photos to the page. You can try manage_pages permission but thats for the admin.

Comment: I even tried making a photo album on the page - and tried posting to the pages photo album. That didn't post to my wall but gave me an facebookErrDomain error 10000

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/206254392780441) in facebook am posting the steps:

1. If you want to post an image on facebook page then you have to be the admin of that page which means that non-admin people cannot post any pics on the FB page, this might sound weird but it seems to be some sort of bug in the facebook
2. You have to use the page access_token and not the user access_token which means that by default you get a access_token when you login using the graph api, but in this case you want to post to a page not to your wall or your friends wall so you need to call one api to request the page acces_token with the help of graph api.
3. You have to call me/accounts api with the access_token that you have got while login as a parameter using the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions because these are the page permissions that allow you to handle the task related to pages.
4. If you do not get the page access_token then the image will be posted on your FB wall since the access_token is the user access_token and not the page access_token.

Another work round could be to carry out this via php server side code.